# Where is 佐賀線偲橋, a bridge on a railway line reconverted into a bicycle path?

Tags: trains, where-on-earth, bicycles, kyushu

佐賀線偲橋 is a bridge in [Saga](https://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Saga) that can serve as a starting point for the 佐賀線跡 tour, which leads tourists along the former tracks of a reconverted railway line ([JR Saga Line](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E4%BD%90%E8%B3%80%E7%B7%9A)).

[image]

What are the latitude/longitude of this bridge?
Google Maps has no idea.

Comment: Removed the [identify-this] tag, you already know what it is :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is located at **33.2438308, 130.3149265**.

This is the location in [Google Maps](https://www.google.com/maps/@33.2438669,130.3150118,143m/data=!3m1!1e3?hl=en) and this is a [Google Maps photo](https://www.google.com/maps/@33.243899,130.314933,3a,75y,90t/data=!3m8!1e2!3m6!1s52512443!2e1!3e10!6s%2F%2Flh4.googleusercontent.com%2Fproxy%2FratruM8jLHuguph5IcvyedzTfz-DzhDFIEFp_AatUSXunBFYspZd2hfvUYL94uOT_vKD1j81aV4CbUrW3sHRu7MSVcpBIg%3Dw203-h114!7i1600!8i900?hl=en) of the same location.

Comment: Wonderful! Just curious, how did you manage to find that information?

Comment: @nic: Somehow not noticing that Heidel had already answered, I found the same place by looking around on Google Maps southeast of Saga for something that looked like the alignment of a former railway line going in the rough direction of Setaka. There is only one such feature, and the inner several kilometers of it seem to have been converted to streets. Then it's just a matter of checking Street View at each place where the line/street goes over a bridge of some kind.

Comment: Nic, I simply Googled "佐賀線偲橋 latitude" and found a Japanese page with some details.

Comment: I was also beaten on this one while searching. You can find a list of the old stations along the line and their locations on Wikipedia, the first stop after Saga (Saga South) is located here: 33°14'22.7"N+130°19'05.7"E and you can easily spot where the old line has branched of to the south, just east of Saga station. The pedestrian/bicycle path starts just north of Saga South station.